# which statistics test I need to find the significance

Tags: statistics

I am not sure which statistics testing technique I need to evaluate my results :( I tested 30 samples by three different techniques. How to find statistically which technique is better in the following cases?

comparing the three in one test?

compare pair in three different tests, eg tech1 and tech2, tech1 and tech3, tech2 and tech3?

Thanks alot.

Comment: You might also try your question at http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

so i applied ttest for 1 & 2, 2 & 3 and 1 & 3 in Microsoft excel.

Because the same samples were evaluated using 3 different techniques I used the formula

To do TTest for A, B

=ttest( 30 values of A, 30 values of B, 2, 1)